# Can't connect to mysql remote server using mysqldump

Tags: sql, networking, mysql

Is it possible to use `mysqldump` between version 5.0 and version 5.5 MySql servers?
I m using this statement:

```
mysqldump -h192.168.1.90 -uBackup_User -p5fudydwkkdfUGEMu -P 3306 --opt --compress --add-drop-database --add-drop-table rb_workflow | mysql -uroot -ppepejeans rb_workflow
```

And it gives error:

> Cannot connect to server on '192.168.1.90'

where 192.168.1.90 have mysql5.5
and the other server has mysql5.0

Is the error coming because of this reason or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open specific port because of security reason. Try a telnet on mysql remote port and see if it is open.

Is this server inside your network? Because the ip you try to reach is an internal one. You have to look for the external IP to if this server is not in your internal network.

Use this command to test the port:

telnet 192.168.1.90 3306

**EDIT: Open a specific port**

*On GNU/Linux server*
Have a look at this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html.

Step 7 explain how to open the port.

*On windows server*

Someone post something similar on mysql website. Have look at this link http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,156915,157606#msg-157606

Comment: both the servers are on internal network. and mysql server installed on port 3306. :/ 
i dont get what you are saying "telnet on mysql remote port and see if it is open"

Comment: For security reason port 3306 is maybe not reachable from other server than the one where mysql is install. You have to test it using telnet from the server where mysqldump is launch to see if the remote server returns packets from port 3306.

Comment: it gave me the result: 
could not open connection to the host. No port 3306. connect failed. 

What to do ? it is installed/connected on 3306 port

Comment: That's what I though. You have to open the port through the firewall. I'll look for the command.

Comment: On `192.168.1.90` server, in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` add in `INPUT` section `-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT` and then do `/etc/init.d/iptables start`

Comment: @mirkobrankovic lol I just wanted him to learn it by himself but nice comment.

Comment: i dont have a linux server. i have windows server. windows command please :)

Comment: Ho sorry :) try this http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,156915,157606#msg-157606

Comment: that was done. now this error is comming : 
Giving error 1064 mysql 42000 when using mysqldump. Source machine is mysql5.5 and destination machine is mysql5.0

Comment: Ok now try to add this comment to the dump --compatible=name.Change name by the good version. [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html)